# Android How to get force app exit Event?

Tags: android, lifecycle

My task is to make a flag true when the user forcefully exits from app. My app contains more than 20 Activities.

Comment: define "forcefully exit"

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no way to listen to forcefull kill of an app event.
As there wont be any app instance available in memory to recieve such an event "if any"

However you can achieve the same behavior by saving a `preference` boolean when the user exits the app gracefully.
So when the app is launched next time, you can check the `graceful_exit` boolean preference, if its not set you know that you app was forcefully killed by system / user

Comment: thanks Arun, but the problem is that , if a user not exit force fully . than also the graceful_exit is true , because we are making this boolean T/F in on stop method . and on stop method call every normal exit and activity normal kill event as well .

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18051137/will-activity-run-ondestroy-when-system-kill-it
I think you might need to consider putting the boolean or pref in onDestroy rather than onStop. As if onDestroy is called it would mean the app exited in a less "ungraceful" manner